# Move NSButton swift

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I have a `NSButton` named round, and I need to change its position according to the previous position, e.g. move it 100 pixels to the right. How to do that? I'm new to swift, so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the frame of the button, basically changing the `x`
 coordinate with 100 pixels to the right, that means increasing it by 100.
See the code below

```
var button  = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50));
var frame = button.frame
frame.origin.x += 100
button.frame = frame
```